# How do i quickly silence all notifications except for ringer on an iPhone 6?

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications

Sometimes I'm on call for work overnight and would like to know a quick way that I can silence all notifications except for the call ringer.  The closest thing I see is allowing calls from everyone on do not disturb but that will allow messages to ring as well.

Answer (score 12):

Actually, Do Not Disturb is indeed your solution as it blocks ALL notifications EXCEPT the calls which you specifically allow. It will block message notifications.

After you have configured the settings in Settings -> Do Not Disturb, all you need to do to enable it is swipe up from the bottom of the screen and tap the moon icon.

You can configure it to only allow certain contact groups, favorites, all callers, and/or repeated calls.

Comment: The problem is that I need to be able to receive calls from many different phones that I do not have as contacts (I work for a hospital). However I don't want to be awoke by texts from friends. Is there a way to allow calls from anyone but not notify for texts?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned, all you need to do is set Do Not Disturb to all "all calls". After that it will silence messages (and other notifications such as email social networks, etc) and will allow all calls. Did you try that?

Comment: Yes it works. I guess I was mislead by the caption that said incoming calls and messages will be silenced from everyone. Tested it with another phone and works as described. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I have the same question as OP, but am unclear on one thing. In the Do Not Disturb settings (iOS 10 now) there are just two options for Silence: [Always] and [Only while iPhone is locked]. If I *don't* want my iPhone's ringer to be silenced while locked it looks like I don't have any options. Am I misunderstanding something, or can I not receive ring notifications when my phone is in its usual state (locked and in my pocket)?

Comment: @Mentalist, notice that DND only applies to notifications *other than* calls if you set it up like so. All you need to do is set Allow Calls From = "Everyone", and make sure that the silence switch on the side of your phone is off (ringer will be audible). The setting you mentioned won't make a difference.

Comment: @bassplayer7 Thanks. The trouble is, if I have the silence switch off *all my other apps* make noise. For example, when I'm at work and I get text messages from my wife I don't want to annoy everyone else in the office with notification bleeps. On the other hand, I can't afford to miss calls from my boss because the silence switch was on. I really only want my iPhone to make sound when I get calls (and preferably only calls from contacts in a "work" group). Is there any way to configure this?

Comment: Yes, you can do that by turning the silence switch off and DND on. Other notifications won't buzz your phone.

Answer (score 0):

You can also head to Settings->Sounds->Text Tone and set tone and vibration there. You can configure texts for no sound and/or no vibration. Similarly, you can allow ALL calls (from any number) to ring as you have set in Settings->Sounds->Ringtone

I was just dealing with the same issue as I expect and need to hear work calls (any number) but can't have my phone buzzing from a bunch of texts all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Try and place your do not disturb button on, "ON"  and that would just allow your phone to ring and will block all other incoming notifications.
I have iphone 7

Answer (score 0):

With the 7/7 Plus you simply engage Do Not Disturb and select "Allow Calls" from "Everyone". Nice and easy.